# PowerQuery returning a value depending on the date falling into a predefined range of dates

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

This is my first question so apologies if I have not asked it as clearly as I should have! As you will likely see my primary task at work is not Power Querying things :)

I am currently simply creating a table that merges (not sure if this is the correct word!) data from two tables to produce a third table, showing mineral percentages and density depending on load origin and material type.

My query output looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(LoadTrak_2100rows,{"Load Origin", "Material"},Schedule,{"Name", "Material"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {"Waste tonnes", "Total Ore Tonnes", "Dil cu_pct", "Dil au", "Dil ag", "Dil fe_pct", "Dil zn_pct", "Density", "Activity"}, {"NewColumn.Waste tonnes", "NewColumn.Total Ore Tonnes", "NewColumn.Dil cu_pct", "NewColumn.Dil au", "NewColumn.Dil ag", "NewColumn.Dil fe_pct", "NewColumn.Dil zn_pct", "NewColumn.Density", "NewColumn.Activity"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{"Record", "Dir.", "Operator", "Truck ID", "Load (m3)", "Truck Operator", "Crew", "Shift", "Material", "Load Origin", "Dumped At", "NewColumn.Dil cu_pct", "NewColumn.Dil au", "NewColumn.Dil ag", "NewColumn.Dil fe_pct", "NewColumn.Dil zn_pct", "NewColumn.Density", "Day", "Shift Time", "Calc Shift"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Blank Rows",{{"NewColumn.Dil au", "Diluted Au g/t"}, {"NewColumn.Dil ag", "Diluted Ag g/t"}, {"NewColumn.Dil cu_pct", "Diluted Cu %"}, {"NewColumn.Dil fe_pct", "Diluted Fe %"}, {"NewColumn.Dil zn_pct", "Diluted Zn %"}, {"NewColumn.Density", "In Situ Density"}, {"NewColumn.Waste tonnes", "Scheduled Waste Tonnes"}, {"NewColumn.Total Ore Tonnes", "Scheduled Ore tonnes"}, {"NewColumn.Activity", "Activity"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

This is fine if my mineral content doesn't change throughout the month (each month will have its own workbook). Alas the mineral content does for some depending, on the Load Origin and date.

In the LoadTrak_2100rows table I have a date for each row (each load has a row). In the Schedule table I have a row with mineral values and a start and end date. An example is below:

So, finally my question. How do I return values for

`"Dil cu_pct", "Dil au", "Dil ag", "Dil fe_pct", "Dil zn_pct", "Density"`
Depending on the date from LoadTrak_2100rows falling into the start and end date defined in Schedule?

I normally hit rocks with a hammer for a living so please bear with me on this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Mat

---

I cannot work out how to attach a sample file (sorry!) but here is an attempt to explain. I have whittled down the two tables to the essentials for the purpose of the questions (I probably should have done this to begin with!).

Essentially my Schedule table looks like this:
[Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSOp2.png)

And my truckloads log look like this
[Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9cnS.png)

What I am wanting is an output that will correlate the schedule Cu% with the loads log. I can currently do this fine, so long as the Cu% does not change throughout the month. But with some locations the Cu% will change through the month and I want my output to reflect this.

Thanks again for your help, apologies I cannot attach the file, I really am not sure if it is possible? I had to remove my image from the original question to add the two follow up ones as I am not allowed to post images yet and am limited to 2 links.

Mat

Comment: can you add the sample excel file with some data which is not sensitive for you ?

Comment: I am more than happy to but I am not sure if it is possible? I cannot find anywhere that tells how to attach a file to a post! Anyway I hope this helps:

Comment: Ok so that didn't seem to do anything. Let me keep trying.

Comment: I have edited the original question with images of the tables, hope this helps! Thanks.

Comment: you can use the hyperlink to send a link to your file where you have uploaded the sample file to a cloud ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you join your tables, you can add a new column with the record from Schedule that corresponds with the date of the load:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Loads,{"From", "Material"},Schedule,{"Location", "Material"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Schedule", (Load) => Table.SelectRows(Load[NewColumn], each [From] <= Load[Timestamp] and [To] >= Load[Timestamp])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"NewColumn"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Now you can proceed like in your original query with expanding this column etcetera.

Comment: Hi Marcel, apologies for my late reply (I have been away for work for the last 6 days). I will give this a try and let you know how I go. Thanks again. Mat

Comment: Hi Marcel, thanks for the help. Unfortunately I now get an error saying "Token Comma Expected", when i click on "show error" it highlights #"Added Custom" but I cannot find anything more than that. There doesn't seem to be a step by step error correction function like in excel so I am kinda stumped. I have found a definition of each function on the Microsoft website but it doesn't really explain how they work, it just says what each part of the function needs to be. Thanks a lot for your help though, i really appreciate it!